# Scheme and Shallow Binding

Tags: binding, scheme

```
 (define make (lambda (x) (lambda (y) (cons x (list y)))))

 (let ((x 7)
       (p (make 4)))
   (cons x (p 0)))
```

I'm new to Scheme and functional program, so I am a bit clunky with walking through programs, but I get that if I used deep binding this program will return (7 4 0). Makes sense. What would this program do using shallow binding? I get this may sound dumb but is the p in the line with cons a redefinition? So in that case, we would return (7 0)?

Basically, I understand the concept of deep v. shallow binding, but I feel like I'm jumbling it up when looking at Scheme because I'm not crazy familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Lexical_scoping_and_dynamic_scoping) for a discussion on scoping (it mentions lexical/dynamic scoping and deep/shallow binding) bearing in mind that Scheme is lexically scoped. Will Ness' answer provides additional information.
For now, let's see step-by-step what's happening in this snippet of code:

```
; a variable called x is defined and assigned the value 7
(let ((x 7)
; make is called and returns a procedure p, inside its x variable has value 4
      (p (make 4)))
; 7 is appended at the head of the result of calling p with y = 0
  (cons x (p 0)))

=> '(7 4 0)
```

Notice that in the second line a *closure* is created in the lambda returned by `make`, and the variable `x` inside will be assigned the value `4`. This `x` has nothing to do with the outer `x`, because Scheme is lexically scoped.

The last line is not a redefinition, as mentioned in the previous paragraph the `x` inside `make` is different from the `x` defined in the `let` expression.

Comment: AFAIK this is wrong. shallow/deep binding is completely orthogonal to static/dynamic scoping. both can be used to implement both. look up "rerooting", it only makes sense in shallow binding impl'n of static scoping.

Comment: @WillNess maybe you can suggest a way to rephrase the first sentence? the rest of the answer is correct, no need to down vote. It'd be better to provide constructive feedback.

Comment: I don't think I was being non-constructive here. The first paragraph is (was) plainly wrong in its totality, I had no choice but to downvote, sorry . :) It can only be removed, or completely re-written. (minimal edit .... done. :) )

Comment: @WillNess ok, agreed. I edited it with a mention to your answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

Deep or shallow binding is an implementational technique and can not be observed from inside the program. The difference for the programmer is between lexical and dynamic scoping rules, but both can be implemented with any of the two techniques (i.e. one notion has got nothing to do with the other).

Deep or shallow refers to the choice of stack frame to hold a given outer scoped variable's binding. In deep binding there is a chain of frames to be accessed until the correct frame is entered holding the record for the variable; in shallow binding all bindings are present in one, shallow environment. See also "rerooting" (which only makes sense in the context of shallow binding implementation of lexical scoping).

To your specific question, under *lexical* scoping rules your code would return `(7 4 0)` and under *dynamic* - `(7 7 0)`, because the call `((lambda(y) (list x y)) 0)` is done inside the dynamic scope of `x=7` binding (as a side note, `(cons x (list y))` is the same as `(list x y)`):

```
x = 7
p = (lambda (y) (list x y))      ; x=4 is unused, in p=(make 4)
(cons 7 (p 0)) == (list 7 7 0)   ; 'x' in this line and in lambda body for p
                                 ;   both refer to same binding that is
                                 ;   in effect, i.e. x=7
```

---

NB same terms (deep/shallow binding) are used in other language(s) now with completely different meaning (they do have something to do with the scoping rules there), which I don't care to fully understand. This answer is given in the context of Scheme.

Reference: [Shallow Binding in LISP 1.5](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/41975) by Baker, Henry G. Jr., 1977.

Comment: Some instructors and textbook authors believe that the difference between deep or shallow binding can be observed and give students assignments to compose a program that gives different results depending on what type of binding is implemented in the PL implementation. That instead of teaching something useful. The difference between lexical and dynamic scoping is a piece of scholasticism because nobody uses dynamic scoping. The difference between deep or shallow binding is even greater piece of scholasticism. :-(

Comment: @beroal my answer talks about the original concept from Lisp world. some pythonistas (or something) very confusedly (and confusingly) used this term to mean something completely different. your comment might be referring to the latter, my answer deals with the former. also, plenty people use dynamic binding in plenty situations. think EMACS Lisp for one thing. (there is no dynamic scoping BTW, 'scope' implies 'lexical'). deep/shallow binding (the original concept) pertains only to the language implementer, not user. it's a valid technique, can be fitting e.g. in Lisp->C translators.