# Shallow vs. Deep binding in scheme

Tags: binding, scheme

Assuming dynamic scoping, what would be the difference in the display statement if it was shallow or deep binding?
I understand that shallow binding is when it is bound at the call and deep is when it is bound while passed as a parameter but I'm not sure how this works in the context of scheme. I think that the deep binding should print 2 but I'm not sure

```
(define A 
    (let* ((x 2)
           (C (lambda (P) 
                 (let ((x 4))
                    (P))))
           (D (display x))
           (B (let ((x 3))
                   (C D))))
        (B)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scheme and Shallow Binding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15013254/scheme-and-shallow-binding)

Comment: @greenteam could you give your sources perhaps for your interpretation of what shallow/deep binding is? Also, Scheme is lexical, so maybe you meant lisp in general and if so should this be retagged as "lisp" perhaps?

Comment: it was wrong to make that edit as it changed the post too much, so I rolled back.

Comment: @WillNess entirely honestly this question is from when I was taking a functional programming class in college 3 years ago and I haven't looked at the material since the class ended. I'd be lying if I said I remember the difference well enough to explain it. If I remember correctly, deep binding is taking on the scope of the parent function of the function in question and shallow binding is taking the scope of the last function to call the function in question. (apologies if that wording was confusing)

Comment: thanks for the reply. it was entirely alright for you to ask this question, and the wording in it is perfectly fine. You can look into the edit history, [one edit before last](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40011675/3), for an illustration. -- I don't know who invented this thing but reusing established terminology like that is not right. maybe you remember the name of that textbook? if not, never mind.

Comment: @WillNess I think it may have been called Programming Language Pragmatics if I remember correctly but I'm not sure this was even terminology from the book but more likely from lecture/homework problems

Comment: thanks. btw, the reference is [Shallow Binding in LISP 1.5](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/41975).

Answer (score 0):

Let's get some definitions into play:

- **Deep binding** binds the environment at the time a procedure is passed as an
  argument.
- **Shallow binding** binds the environment at the time a procedure is actually called

So the only difference will be regarding the evaluation of C which happens inside B.

```
(define A 
    (let* ((x 2)
           (C (lambda (P) 
                 (let ((x 4))
                    (P))))
           (D (display x))
           (B (let ((x 3))
                   (C D))))
        (B)))
```

On the other hand, the code itself seems to be buggy, (display x) will not return a value yet it is passed into C.

Let's assume you meant `(D (lambda () (display x)))`

```
(define A 
    (let* ((x 2)
           (C (lambda (P) 
                 (let ((x 4))
                    (P))))
           (D (lambda () (display x)))
           (B (let ((x 3))
                   (C D))))
        (B)))
```

under deep binding the value of x is 3 when D is passed into C, so we should expect 3 to be printed.

under shallow binding the value of x is 4 when the procedure is actually called, so 4 will be printed.

Comment: And I think you are confused because it asks about deep and shallow binding in the context of Scheme, which are nothing like you describe. Again, what you describe relates to similarly named yet *completely different* concepts in ***other*** languages. But the question is about Scheme. In Scheme, the meaning of these terms is clear, and it is *not* what you describe. there simply is no such thing as "shallow or deep dynamic scope" in Scheme. the phrase is meaningless in the context of Scheme.

Comment: another thing is, you only caught one error. as written, your second snippet still causes an error when B is called as a procedure after being set to some numerical value, whether 2, 3, or 4.